# Jenkins Related Issue-Copying artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wanted to copy the artifacts present in one job to another job.The problem is the path given is relative to

$JENKINS_HOME/userContent
Now my data exists inside one of the jobs how do i copy that??

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you are using "Copy Artifacts from another project" post-build action, right?

The location from which the artifacts are copied from is relative to:
- the **artifacts** folder, 
- for the selected build, 
- for the job you selected to copy from

So, first things first, you have to make sure that the job that you are copying from is actually archiving the artifacts. It will not copy files from workspace (there are other plugins for that).

To archive your artifacts, in the job the creates them, select post-build action "Archive the artifacts", then provide a list of artifacts you want to archive, relative to workspace. For example, to archive all zip files, regardless of where they are, use:

```
**/*.zip
```

Or if you know that all your artifacts are inside the "build" folder, but there may be intermediate directories in between, use:

```
build/**/*.zip
```

Or simply provide a full path:

```
build/myartifactsfolder/myfile.zip
```

Now, to view the artifacts available, navigate in your browser to the URL of the job from which you want to copy, select the build you wish to copy from, and then append /artifact/ at the end, or just click "Build Artifacts" link on the page:

```
example: http://localhost/job/YourJob/lastBuild/artifact/
```

This will show a directory structure and all available artifacts.
You can reference this in the "Copy Artifacts" post-build step directly. Or you can use wildcards. For example, if you want to ignore any directory structure, and just copy all *.zip files, your "Artifacts to copy" field should be:

```
**/*.zip
```

The double stars ignore directories in between.
You can use comma to separate multiple entries. Alternatively, if you leave this field blank, it will copy all available artifacts.

On the receiving end, the "Target directory" is relative to the **Workspace** of the job that is calling the "Copy Artifacts" step.

Lastly, if you don't care about the directory structure, check mark the "Flatten directories" option, so that all artifacts end up in the same place, ignoring any folders in between.

Comment: any idea how to ignore artifact case sensitivity with this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

- Have *Job-A* save its artifacts to a shared location.
- Have *Job-B* read the artifacts of *Job-A* from that shared location.

Case you want to save multiple copies of the artifacts of *Job-A* (like the history of the last 10 builds),
have *Job-A* pass the exact location of the relevant artifacts to *Job-B* via a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1 First install copy artifact plugin
Then add build step to your job and select copy artifacts from project.
2 Give the appropriate project name(job that is creating the zip/war etc) and build number too if required.
 Now focus on Artifacts to copy field..e.g give **/*zip 
This will search the *zip inside the artifact folder of the mentioned project in step 2 and copy the entire structure including .zip inside the workspace of the present job.
e.g if zip is inside /artifact/xyz/www.zip then entire structure i.e xyz/www.zip will be copied to your workspace .To avoid this copying the entire structure and copy only zip,you can use flatten directory option.